# SSIS package: Fuzzy lookup triggers SQLDUMPER_ERRORLOG.log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I use SQL 2008 R2. When I execute the package including fuzzy lookup, it shows the number of rows transferred from OLEDB source to Fuzzy LookUp, but after that it is not processing the records.  There is no error ,both OLE DB source and fuzzy lookup turned Yellow and continued as yellow. There is no output from Fuzzy Look Up and so the destination object didn't executed (didn't even turn to Yellow) and generate SQLDUMPER_ERROLOG.log. I set Run64BitRuntime as True. I also make sure all the lengths of the input columns match those of the reference columns. Can anyone help with this issue? Thanks,

Comment: Assuming the SQL Server and Visual Studio are both patched up, I'd say you're looking at a call to MS support.